# CodeIgniter Database Caching is caching Session Flashdata - making it persist for too long

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session, caching

I am building an application which uses Flashdata to display messages to the user after certain actions - e.g. "Item Successfully Removed", etc.  I am also using CodeIgniter's Database Query Caching in order cache certain queries until I invalidate them.

After editing an item, I set a Flashdata message to say "Item Edited". I then `redirect()` to the All Items view - which displays the Flashdata message. **However, this Flashdata message persists even when I reload the page**. The only way to get it to disappear is by emptying out the `application/cache` directory.

Is there any sensible way of overriding the Caching mechanism to not cache Flashdata? I have found this - http://codeigniter.com/wiki/No_Flash_Cache - but it seems to be a very old solution for CI 1.7. I gave it a go anyway but for some reason CI didn't want to override the private function `_write_cache()` - it would override everything else just fine though... *(Edit: realised now that (unless someone tells me otherwise) that only affects Output caching - not Database caching)*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure you are not using `$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');` in your code.

Comment: Does it reappear if you navigate away from the page and go back to it? If not, it could be a browser caching problem. Check the Net tab in Firebug/Chrome dev tools and see if the server is sending a 304 (unchanged) header. If it is, then that's your problem and CI is not at fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the cache mechanism of codeigniter by using cache_override hook. Following lines have been copied from their documentation

> **cache_override:** Enables you to call your own function instead of the
>   _display_cache() function in the output class. This permits you to use your own cache display mechanism.